# Delete duplicate files with Powershell except the file specified

Tags: powershell

I am using the following code to delete duplicate files in one folder:

```
ls *.wav -recurse | get-filehash | group -property hash | where { $_.count -gt 1 } | % { $_.group | select -skip 1 } | del
```

I have two issues. I want to limit this to only one filehash at a time and I need to specify the file name I want to keep.

As an example, I have a folder named Recordings. The first five files listed all have the same filehash but only one has the filename that has already been entered in my database.

[Recordings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLsW4.png)

It would be great if I could use the -Exclude parameter for the del cmdlet but that parameter does not accept pipeline input.

I also considered using the code above and then renaming the remaining file afterward but the code is not limited to one filehash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you want it to work. For example, if you know the file name you want to keep in advance, you could do it this way:

```
$fileName = 'file1.txt'
$fileHash = Get-FileHash .\$filename
$duplicates = ls -Recurse | Get-FileHash | Where-Object {$_.Hash -eq $fileHash.Hash -and ($_.Path | Split-Path -Leaf) -ne $fileName }
$duplicates | del
```

This sequence sets the filename, gets the hash of that file, and then the main command checks for other files with that same hash that doesn't have the same filename.

**Note**: Test first to make sure this will do what you expect before you execute the del command.

**Update**: It appears that Get-FileHash puts some sort of lock on the files being hashed so you cannot immediately pipe to the del (Remove-Item) command. I modified the results to save the array of duplicates to a variable and then pass that to the delete command which works.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great solution. However, when I use it, I get the following error for every file. `del : Cannot remove item C:\Recordings4\07fade58.4425.4004.891f.4d494c193641 07-27-2016.wav: The process cannot access
the file 'C:\Recordings4\07fade58.4425.4004.891f.4d494c193641 07-27-2016.wav' because it is being used by another
process.` I searched for and found no PID related to any of the files so I am not able to use the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using Process Explorer to see if you can determine what has them locked. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Comment: I did that and nothing has them locked.

Comment: OK, I didn't actually test the deletion part previously. I was able to duplicate what you are seeing and it appears to be something with Get-FileHash. I edited my answer with a workaround.

Comment: Awesome. This works exactly as described. Thank you!